# What is the meaning of $F_{p^k}$ and the elliptic curve over it, $E(F_{p^k})$?

Tags: elliptic-curves, finite-field

In pairing based cryptography, there will be the finite field $F_{p^k}$ where $p$ is prime number and $k$ is an integer. The elliptic curve is constructed on that finite field as $E(F_{p^k})$.

For example, let $E$ be an elliptic curve $Y^2 = X^3 + aX + b $ over $ F_{q^k}$. What is the meaning of $ F_{q^k}$ here? I only understand prime fields ($F_q$ where q is a prime number).

Comment: There is an introduction in Wikipedia about [Finite Fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field), and this is a wide subject ( there are already 4K questions in [math.se](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finite-fields) about it. If you are going to learn about more Finite Field, you should take a course or read a book about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A finite field $(\mathbb F,+,\cdot)$ is a finite set $\mathbb F$ with two internal laws $+$ and $\cdot$, such that $(\mathbb F,+)$ is a commutative [group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)) with neutral noted $0$, and $(\mathbb F-\{0\},\cdot)$ is a commutative group with neutral noted $1$, and multiplication is distributive w.r.t. addition that is $\forall A,B,C\in\mathbb F$ it holds $A\cdot(B+C)=(A\cdot B)+(A\cdot C)$.

It can be shown that all finite fields with the same number of elements are [isomorphic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism), that is we can map from one to another by a [bijection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection) $\mathcal F$ such that $\mathcal F(A+B)=\mathcal F(A)+\mathcal F(B)$ and $\mathcal F(A\cdot B)=\mathcal F(A)\cdot \mathcal F(B)$. We can thus talk about *the* finite field $\mathbb F$ with $q$ elements. It's often noted $\mathbb F_q$.

It can be shown that any finite field has a number $q$ of elements of the form $q=p^k$ for some prime $p$ and some $k\in\mathbb N^*$.

When $k=1$, the field $(\mathbb F_p,+,\cdot)$ is simply the ring of integers modulo $p$, that is $(\mathbb Z_p,+,\cdot)$.

For arbitrary $k\in\mathbb N^*$, we can think of the field $(\mathbb F_{p^k},+,\cdot)$ as the set of polynomials of degree up to $k-1$ and coefficients in $\mathbb Z_p$. That is, polynomials for an abstract variable $x$ with one coefficient in $\mathbb Z_p$ for each of the $k$ terms $x^i$ with $i\in\{0,1\ldots,k-1\}$. Addition in $\mathbb F_{p^k}$ is addition of polynomials. Multiplication in $\mathbb F_{p^k}$ is multiplication of polynomials followed by reduction modulo a particular reduction polynomial $R(x)$ of degree exactly $k$, and [irreducible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_polynomial).

Equivalently, we can think of $\mathbb F_{p^k}$ as the set of $p^k$ tuples of $k$ elements of $\mathbb Z_p$, noted $(a_0,a_1\ldots,a_{k-1})$. Addition is defined by$$(a_0,a_1\ldots,a_{k-1})+(b_0,b_1\ldots,b_{k-1})=(a_0+b_0,a_1+b_1\ldots,a_{k-1}+b_{k-1})$$with the later additions carried in $\mathbb Z_p$, that is with reduction modulo $p$. If the tuple $A$ has $a_i=1$ and all the other terms $0$, and the tuple $B$ has $b_j=1$ and all the other terms $0$, then when $i+j<k$ the tuple $C$ for $A\cdot B$ has $c_{i+j}=1$ and all the other terms $0$. When $i+j=k$, the tuple $C$ for $A\cdot B$ is a constant tuple $(r_0,r_1,\ldots,r_{k-1})$ independent of $i$ and $j=k-i$. That tuple is such that the polynomial $R(x)=x^k-r_{k-1}\,x^{k-1}\ldots-r_1\,x-r_0$ with coefficients in $\mathbb Z_p$ is [irreducible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_polynomial), implying $r_0\ne0$. This constant tuple $(r_0,r_1\ldots,r_{k-1})$, or equivalently the polynomial $R(x)$, combined with the previously stated rules and properties of $+$ and $\cdot$, fully defines multiplication, and it's neutral $(1,0\ldots,0)$.

We can compute the tuple $(c_0,c_1\ldots,c_{k-1})$ for $(a_0,a_1\ldots,a_{k-1})\cdot(b_0,b_1\ldots,b_{k-1})$ as follows:

- $(c_0,c_1\ldots,c_{k-1}):=(0,0\ldots,0)$
- for $i$ from $k-1$ down to $0$

  - $m:=c_{k-1}$
  - for $j$ from $k-1$ down to $1$

    - $c_j:=m\cdot r_j+a_i\cdot b_j+c_{j-1}$
  - $c_0:=m\cdot r_0+a_i\cdot b_0$

  with the computations in the last two lines carried in $\mathbb Z_p$, that is modulo $p$.

Comment: I just want to add a small point: in the context of pairing based cryptography, the $k$ is usually the embedding degree. I.e. it's the smallest $k$ such that $n | q^k-1$ where $n$ is the number of points in the elliptic curve group.

It's important to choose curves with small values of $k$ otherwise pairings are too expensive to compute.

Answer (score 3):

You can consider it's $F_q[X]/(P(X))$ with $P$ an [irreducible polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_polynomial) of degree $k$ in $F_q[X]$.

It means the elements of the field can be seen are polynomials and when you do an addition or a multiplication, you are computing it modulo $P$.

Toy example:
Let suppose $q=2=k$. We can take $P=X^2 + X + 1$ which is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

All elements are of the form: $\alpha_0 + \alpha_1 X$.

Let $\alpha_0 + \alpha_1 X, \beta_0 + \beta_1 X$ two elements of the field.
$\alpha_0 + \alpha_1 X +  \beta_0 + \beta_1 X=  (\alpha_0 + \beta_0) + (\alpha_1 + \beta_1) X$

$(\alpha_0 + \alpha_1 X) \cdot  (\beta_0 + \beta_1 X)=  (\alpha_0\beta_0) + (\alpha_1\beta_0 + \alpha_0\beta_1) X + \alpha_1\beta_1X^2$.
And because $X^2 =X +1 $, it's equal to
$(\alpha_0 + \alpha_1 X) \cdot  (\beta_0 + \beta_1 X)=  (\alpha_0\beta_0+ \alpha_1\beta_1) + (\alpha_1\beta_0 + \alpha_0\beta_1 + \alpha_1\beta_1) X$.

To compute the invert of $(\alpha_0 + \alpha_1 X)$, we have to solve the system:
$(\alpha_0x_0+ \alpha_1x_1)=1$ and
$ (\alpha_1x_0 + (\alpha_0+ \alpha_1)x_1)=0$.

Comment: Thank you, can you give an example that can simply explain $F_{q}[X]$

Comment: @xiaojiuwo Is it clearer?